# Missing tasks in VSTS

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am currently trying to a build definition on VSTS. I am using [Hosted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/services/hosted-agent-pool) agent, but for some reason it seems i am missing a lot of built in tasks. I am missing several of the tasks below.

[image: screenshoot are from https://www.visualstudio.com/features/alm-devops-vs]

I want to deploy my application after running build and test, but the IIS Web Application Deployment is not available, any suggestions? Do i need to create my own powershell script to deploy?

According to [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/387), the task might not be live yet? But this is a pretty old issue, so not sure if the information there are still relevant.

This is a screenshot of what i have in the "Deploy" category: 
[image: What i actually have]

Comment: IIS Web Application Deployment task should be deployed and available to you. If you're using the hosted or a custom agent should also not matter, since the task are deployed to the VSTS collection and not to the agent.

Do you want to use it in a build or release definition? And I assume you are using the new web based build system and not a XAML build?

Comment: Yes i do require it as a step in our build process, and yes i am using the web based build system. What i find strange is a missing a lot of other tasks as well. If the tasks in the screenshot above i only have Azure Web App Deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIS Web Application Deployment task still seems to be [in preview](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/IISWebAppDeployment/task.json). Meaning it is deployed to your tenant but not enabled. Therefore you also won't be able to just upload it yourself using Tfx-Cli.

The only way to have access to them seems to be if your tenant is in preview mode which you can request from the address mentioned under contact on [this site](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/IISWebAppDeployment). See also [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/465).

Answer (score 0):

It is already in VSO but not enabled for customers yet. Refer to this link for details: https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/issues/30

Comment: This basically states the same as https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/387. This is a issue from august!? Same with the one you reference. This means i will have to create my own powershell script to be able to do this? Do you know how when it should be released? Also very confusion that these tasks are shown in screenshots, i assumed the tasks where publicly available.

Comment: It is not an issue, this feature is still in preview, so it isn't enabled to customers yet. You can contact the alias RM_Customer_Queries at microsoft dot com if you want to try this feature.