# publish website from vso using web deploy

Tags: webdeploy, azure-devops

In the last couple of days, I spent time trying to find an out-of-box function in visual studio online (vso) publish asp.net website using web deploy, but I haven't found it.

Does this even exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIS Web Application Deployment task is still [in preview](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/IISWebAppDeployment/task.json). Meaning it is deployed to your tenant but not enabled. Therefore you also won't be able to just upload it yourself using Tfx-Cli.

The only way to have access to them seems to be if your tenant is in preview mode which you can request from the address mentioned under contact on [this site](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/IISWebAppDeployment). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593097/missing-tasks-in-vsts/34606028).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the IIS Web Application Deployment task in a release definition.

[image]

Comment: I don't have this option in deploy dialog. How I can find it?

Comment: It must be in preview still.  Try the contact info on this tasks GitHub page.  They may be able to give you early access.  https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/IISWebAppDeployment